# update columns based on query with select

Tags: mysql

I have a data base that I imported into a table called `ip2city` that contains 3 columns `(startipint,endipint,country)`
that is linking a given IP range (represented in integer) to a specific country

I have another table called `Test2` that containing columns source and dest (`INT` representing IP) and empty columns `countryS, countryD` 
I want to fill the empty columns based on the the data from the table `ip2city`

I am new to mysql

I tried something that looks like :

```
UPDATE Test2    
SET CountryS = (SELECT Country FROM `ip2city` WHERE startipint <= Test2.`Source` 
                ORDER BY startipint DESC LIMIT 1);
```

where `select...` is suppose to return the value I want to insert to the table
but it dosnt seem to work

when I just use

```
SELECT * FROM `ip2city` WHERE startipint <= 3232235521 ORDER BY startipint DESC LIMIT 1
```

with specific ip, I get a good result so how can i use it on an entire table.. ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Test2
JOIN ip2city s ON Test2.Source between s.startipint and s.endipint
JOIN ip2city d ON Test2.Dest between d.startipint and d.endipint
SET CountryS = s.country, CountryD = d.country
```

Note that this is a mysql-only solution, because this query uses mysql's [multiple-table update syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ip2city WHERE startipint <= 3232235521 ORDER BY startipint DESC LIMIT 1");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    echo $row['columnname'];
```

Now you can use this in your UPDATE query like this:

```
UPDATE Test2
SET CountryS = $row['columnname']
```

Comment: this doesnt need PHP at all